# Rails: Working on (Updating) 2 different controllers at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, updates

I want to implement a simple discount coupon. I have a model that valid coupons are saved (beside some other things) and a Product model that product features are stored (name, price, ...).

I have a simple form that enables the user to enter his coupon. I should check it to see if it is valid or not (I defined a scope for it). If the entered coupon is valid, I have to update both of the mentioned tables. In the first one, I have to change the coupon to "used" and in the second table, I should update the price with the new value. And I want to do these operations when the user entered a value in the form.

What is your suggestion and solution to do both of them? As these two operations are related to 2 different models and controllers, I cannot access them in one controller. What is the best way to call a method to do these operations? Could you please give me a clear explanation?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I use a form backing object for this type of stuff: https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects

Comment: @ruby_newbie It's not the solution but worth to consider.

Answer (score 2):

You have access to both models in either controller however to do this the "rails way" you should put this logic in your model.  I would add a before_update callback in your coupon model that checks if the coupon is being changed to "used" as you mention.  If so, you can then update its "price" in your product table.  The key concept to takeaway from this is that you can call all Models from anywhere and they are not limited to their respective controllers only.

Comment: Seems, like a logical way to me!

Comment: I had thought to use active record callbacks but I ignored it due a problem. How is it possible to use the before_update callback in the coupon model to update an attribute of the product model? It is not possible and also not "rails way" to call a controller's action in the model.

Comment: You are not calling a controllers action in the model.  When you are changing the state of your coupon instance in your Coupon Model (via an update which is not the update controller action but the update method in your model!) you should then lookup the correlating Product it is associated with (still inside the coupon model using the callback method run when the coupon is updated) and change its price as desired.